# Removing dotted border

Tags: openseadragon

I use the following code to display an image using OpenSeaDragon

```
var newURL='...link to picture...';

var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "id_forPic",
        zoomInButton:   "cs_zoomin",
        zoomOutButton:  "cs_zoomout",
         homeButton:     "cs_reset",
        fullPageButton: "cs_fullpage",
        defaultZoomLevel:1,
        tileSources: {url:newURL,type:'image'}
        
    });
```

When I pan the image then there is a dotted-line behind. Does anyone know how to remove it?
I have tried adding the following to the style-sheet

```
.openseadragon-container  { 
    border: 0px !important;
    border-color:white !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably the focus indicator. You might try this:

```
.openseadragon-container :focus { outline: none; }
```

There's more discussion here: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/893